# Python code: function call not working or something wrong with code

Tags: python

PYTHON VERSION: 2.7.5

I am making a small program which generates a custom sentence for the user dependant on their input. I have tried to make it so that the name() function comes before the chooseColour() function. I called the name() function before, in the code, but it doesn't show up. All I get is 'What is your favourite colour, instead of the name() function showing first. I will enclose the code, and if somebody could copy it and correct it, I can just use the code you have edited.

```
# DoC: 07/12/2016
# Creator: Louis Parkes
# Desc: This program will generate a custom sentence depending on the user's imput.

import time

def displayIntro():
    print("Welcome to the CSG (Custom Sentence Generator)")
    print("Please answer the following questions to create the sentence.")
    print("")
    print("Creator: Louis Parkes")
    print("Contact: my-email")
    print("")
    s1()

def displayEnd():
    print("Thanks for using the CSG!")
    print("We hoped you enjoy the experience!")
    rateByUser = int(raw_input("Please rate your experience, 1 being 1 star and 5 being 5 star."))
    if rateByUser == 1 or rateByUser == 2 or rateByUser == 3 or rateByUser == 4:
        print("Please help us improve by emailing 'my-email'")
    elif rateByUser == 5:
        print("Thanks very much for your response! Have a great day!")
    else:
        print("Error: invalid input.")

def s1():
    time.sleep(1)
def s2():
    time.sleep(0.5)

#==================================================================================================

def name():
    forename = ""
    surname = ""
    while forename == 0 and surname == 0:
        forename = raw_input("What is your forename?: ")
        print("")
        time.sleep(1)
        surname = raw_input("What is your surname?: ")
        print("")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Your name is %s %s! " % (forename, surname))
        time.sleep(0.5)

    return forename
    return surname

    if len(forename) > 5 or len(surname) > 6:
        print("You have a large name, %s! " % (forename, surname))
    elif len(forename) <= 5 or len(surname) <= 6:
        print("You have an average sized name!")
    elif len(forename) > 5 or len(surname) > 6:
        print("You have a small name!")
    else:
        print("Error: Obviously, there is something not right with your input or the code. Please try again. Contact developer if there is a bug.")

s1()
def chooseColour():
    colour = ""
    while len(colour) == 0:
        colour = raw_input("What is your favourite colour?: ")
        s2()
        print("Your favourite colour is %s! " % (colour))

    return colour

displayIntro()
name()
chooseColour()
```

Comment: Please trim your example to [MCVE], especially **minimal** part. Also learn more on [ask].

Comment: You may want to hide your email address in this post

Comment: "I can just use the code you have edited", good algorithm to solve a problem : write total non sense program then wait until someone correct it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: forename = ""

In [2]: forename == 0
Out[2]: False
```

In name(), you should test in the while that forename and surname are empty, not equal to 0.

You have 2 returns in name function. Only the first one will be executed, and nothing will be executed after it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def name():
    forename = ""
    surname = ""
    while not forename and not surname:
        forename = raw_input("What is your forename?: ")
        print("")
        time.sleep(1)
        surname = raw_input("What is your surname?: ")
        print("")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Your name is %s %s! " %(forename, surname))
        time.sleep(0.5)


    if len(forename) > 5 or len(surname) > 6:
        print("You have a large name, %s%s! " % (forename, surname))
    elif len(forename) <= 5 or len(surname) <= 6:
        print("You have an average sized name!")
    elif len(forename) > 5 or len(surname) > 6:
        print("You have a small name!")
    else:
        print("Error: Obviously, there is something not right with your input or the code. Please try again. Contact developer if there is a bug.")

    return forename
    return surname
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `name()` call has no effect because of this:

```
forename = ""
surname = ""
while forename == 0 and surname == 0:
```

The loop condition is never satisfied because `"" != 0`, so the loop block is not executed. Change it to:

```
while forename == "" and surname == "":
```

or:

```
while not (forename or surname):
```

Comment: Great! So was my problem the fact that I assigned forename and surname to an empty string, and I used an integer in the while loop? I assume they are 2 different things.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the problem. You initialized them as empty strings and compared them with 0, which is a different value. Thus, the condition is not satisfied and the loop is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the while loop:

```
def name():
    forename = ""
    surname = ""
    while forename == "" and surname == "":
```

You need to compare these two variables to `""` (an empty string) rather than `0` (an integer)